# Connecting to database server in Perl?

Tags: database, perl

I want to connect to database server using `use DBI` module in Perl.

I don't have any database server installed in my system. Is there a way I can try the database connectivity without actually installing SQL server. I checked SQL server and it is 2.5 GB download

Is it possible to use Perl's `DBI` module without really installing full database server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [DBI DBD:SQLite](http://search.cpan.org/~msergeant/DBD-SQLite-0.31/lib/DBD/SQLite.pm) and an [SQLite Database](http://www.sqlite.org/) the download is only 1.4MB

And  here is a [Tutorial](http://zetcode.com/db/sqliteperltutorial/) to get you started

Comment: Actually half the code in the tutorial looks really old. I recommend not to use this tutorial for anything else but looking at how the SQLite driver works. Most of the code is old-fashioned and will only introduce bugs.

Comment: can you please tell me how to connect `my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:SQLite:dbname=dbfile","",""); Is this is sufficient to connect to databse or we have to change sqlite path

Comment: Can you look into another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21382064/error-while-installing-perl-module-from-cpan

Answer (score 4):

You can use a different [database driver](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#connect). You could use [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.com) for example. Or you could install [xampp](http://www.apachefriends.org/), which brings a [mysql](http://mysql.com) instance.

I recommend using SQLite and the [DBD::SQLite driver](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD%3a%3aSQLite).

Comment: Can you look into another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21382064/error-while-installing-perl-module-from-cpan